# RF help, difference between using 12V and 5V as power supply voltage

Tags: arduino, rf, transmitter, receiver

I am currently looking into building a custom RF transmitter. The commercial ones built for Arduinos usually operate at 5V. I was also looking into some RF remotes, and found that they usually use 12V. I am wondering if this creates a difference in terms of RF output power?

It kind of makes sense for Arduino modules to run on 5V since that is a voltage the Arduino can supply, but would using a 12V circuit improve the output power?

Comment: The lower voltage is easily sufficient to reach *legal* power level limits.   What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  What frequency, modulation and purpose, and what regulatory allowance are you hoping to operate under?

Comment: Hi Chris. I am dealing with 433 MHz ISM band. Modulation is OOK. I am trying to see how much I can extend the range of the transmitter.

Comment: You an *easily* hit the legal power limits for 433 with even just 3v3 supply.  And if your protocol is OOK, you're not going to go very far.  Buying a decent synthesized radio with an SPI interface rather than the usual monstrosities might help a little, but most of the improvement would be on the receiving side and in switching to a better modulation scheme.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, From what you said, working on increasing the gain on the receiver side is more important. For the purposes of this project, I am trying to keep everything as simple as possible and avoiding components that run on interfaces such as I2C or SPI.

Comment: @aeroengineer in doing so you will be limiting yourself to quite "crappy" radios and so frustrating your goal.  The SAW-tx / regen-rx sets with a simply modulation in/out are suitable for short range use only, and ironically require *more* sophistication to the software decoder, since they "invent" signal all by themselves when there is none.

Comment: I see, thank you. So basically there won't be much difference between 12V and 5V input sources if I am using SAW-tx OOK transmitter in that case.

Answer (score 0):

A better receive antenna may help.

You'll find more information at

[433 MHz Antenna - Balanced Dipole + Balun?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/539364/433-mhz-antenna-balanced-dipole-balun/539382#539382)